# Google Drive partially download folders

Tags: google-drive

I used to save my photos is `Google Drive`,
and I want to move it to `Google Photos`.

The photos are arranged in folders and sub-folders.
When I try to download a folder (which contain sub-folders as well)
`Google` zip only few files.
It also gives the zipped file a strange name: `<folder-name>-<date>-003`,
where the `<folder-name>` and `<date>` are replaced with the real names,
but the part number is strange, it seems that it zipped it in multiple parts
but only download one of them.

How can I download the folder or zipped folder with all of the files?